# Loading and unloading css files in Vue 2

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, webpack-style-loader, vue-cli

I have created my project with `vue-cli` and I have loaded css files using `require` in my `main.js` file.

I need to load different css files if user decides to see website in RTL languages (like displaying another theme).

I have searched and read about style-loader, css-loader and vue style-loader, but it all seems vague to me.

Comment: Can't you use [conditional rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)?

Comment: @JulienRousé I dont need different templates, only different styles

Comment: Different approach, but if you had different class name for RTL and non-RTL in your css you might be able to trigger the right css style? Of course you need to load both style everytime which isn't perfect

Comment: That's what I already had in mind. If a better solution is not found I would go for it!

Comment: weird how I still can't find a good answer on how to do this. how to get the loaders to do stuff conditionally?